# In Objective C: How to show 3 values on 1 row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have one Player Object Array with player Name and player Score, I want to show like:

row+1.   Player1 ***_*__**_playerScore1

row+1.   Player2 ***_*__**_playerScore2

row+1.   Player3 ***_*__**_playerScore3

.......

Thank you for your help,

Harry.

Comment: Objective-C is a programming language, not a framework.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout UITableView:

http://www.littlecomputers.net/2009/?page_id=549

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

And also customizing the table view cells:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Hope those helps

edit: I pasted the wrong link in my initial post (one for mono touch - meant to include on for UITableView over array)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about a UITable... I'm using this approach in a current project.

[Creating a grid view in iOS](http://www.recursiveawesome.com/blog/2011/04/06/creating-a-grid-view-in-ios/)

It's very straightforward, assuming you know your way around table controllers. The code on the blog post explains how it's put together. For each row, you simply setup the cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

GridTableViewCell *cell = (GridTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[GridTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.lineColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

// Since we are drawing the lines ourself, we need to know which cell is the top cell in the table so that
// we can draw the line on the top
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    cell.topCell = YES;
else
    cell.topCell = NO;

// Configure the cell.
cell.cell1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
cell.cell2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
cell.cell3.text = @"Sample text";

return cell;
}
```